# Should I use in or of?

Tags: word-choice

Is this sentence:

> Even though I was a stranger to tragedy as a plane descended from
>   17000 feet ***of*** height.

Supposed to be:

> Even though I was a stranger to tragedy as a plane descended from
>   17000 feet ***in*** height.

I have been struggling with this because Grammarly says I am supposed to write "in", yet it feels strange.

Comment: A native speaker would not use either "of height" or "in height"; just say "from 17,000 feet".  If you have to add something else, maybe "... **an altitude of** 17,000 feet."  Do not trust grammar checkers; they are all terrible.

Comment: You do not have a complete sentence. As written, it makes little sense, besides the height issue. The structure is incorrect.

Comment: I would suggest that you stop using grammarly.

Comment: Also, neither of those are sentences because they don't have a main clause. That's the first thing Grammarly should have caught.

Answer (score 1):

You would normally not say either ***in*** **height** or ***of*** **height**, so the distinction is something of a moot point in this case.

Instead, just stop at **feet** since "height" is assumed:

> . . . as a plane descended from 17,000 feet.

Adding additional elements sounds awkward.

---

Note, too, that the sentence itself has a few other problems.

1) Lacking the context of a previous sentence, if you start this one with *even though*, you need to finish the thought:

> Even though (#1 happened), (#2 happened).

But in your sentence, you don't have a concluding thought.

2) It is more common to use *when* than *as* if you are referring to a specific point in time as you are.

3) Unless context makes it clear that the indefinite article is somehow appropriate, my instinct tells me that you're talking about a specific plane, and should be using the definite article instead.

To summarize, the sentence might look something like this:

> Even though I was a stranger to tragedy ***when the*** plane descended from 17,000 feet, *I became acquainted with it when the plane crashed.*

Comment: To the contrary, it seems to me **as** to be more appropriate here. The indefinite article also adds a touch of non-involvement, mere on-looker-ness—some plane descending to its demise. Your 2) is ungrounded, imo - _as = while or when:   I saw Peter as I was getting off the bus. Just as the two men were leaving, a message arrived._